# Cannot find protocol definition for XXX

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have declared a protocol firstly, and then use it. But I get a warning "Cannot find protocol definition for LeveyPopListViewDelegate".
Here is the code:

```
@protocol LeveyPopListViewDelegate;

@interface LeveyPopListView : UIView <LeveyPopListViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

//the content of LeveyPopListView

@end

@protocol LeveyPopListViewDelegate <NSObject>
//the definition for LeveyPopListViewDelegate
@end
```

if I put the definition `LeveyPopListViewDelegate` at first, I can not use the `LeveyPopListView` in the protocol.

Comment: Max_:  While some things we used to do with delegates are now better done with blocks, there are LOTS of reasons to use protocols.

Comment: which version of XCode are you on?

Comment: Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127)

Comment: not that it  matters... your code is running fine without errors for me (XCode4.6) - I just tried it in some older versions in case something had changed, but it's ok also in 4.2 ;-j

Comment: But the weird thing is that despite the warning it does work, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do it this way:

```
@class LeveyPopListView;

@protocol LeveyPopListViewDelegate <NSObject>
//the definition for LeveyPopListViewDelegate
@end

@interface LeveyPopListView : UIView <LeveyPopListViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

//the content of LeveyPopListView

@end
```

Comment: But I want to use LeveyPopListView in `protocol` LeveyPopListViewDelegate

Comment: You can with what I posted. That's the point of the forward class declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why declaring a protocol first will get a warning?

Comment: I've never been able to make forward protocol definitions work so I always do as I posted.

Answer (score 15):

I ended up suppressing all warnings for that particular line, which is not ideal but works well.

```c
// Forward-declare protocols (to avoid circular inclusion)
@protocol YourProtocol;
#pragma clang diagnostic push
// To get rid of 'No protocol definition found' warnings which are not accurate
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything" 

@interface YourClass: NSObject
// <YourProtocol>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Make sure you do push & pop, otherwise you'll end up with all warnings being ignored for this file!

Comment: That did the trick. As I am using a Swift protocol, that was the only way to remove this warning. I also found a good source [here in this blogpost from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/clang-diagnostics/)

Answer (score 2):

If you followed the good advice in this post and still have the issue try just doing a clean. I was scratching my head over it for a while and a clean resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I imported `Swift` protocol to `Objective C` class. What helped me is to add `*-Swift.h` file to the `Objective C` class file:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
```

and declare protocol as `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol VerificationGate
```

Comment: I am curious how that worked out. I have the same warning. It is not possible to import the automatically generated Swift bridging header in Objective-C headers as it is not generated yet. It can only be imported in Objective-C implementation files. But the protocol conformance is defined in Objective-C headers. A forward declaration in the Objective-C header does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you declared and defined protocol in different file, you have to `#import` that file, forward declaration won't help in this situation.

BTW. Never suppress warnings as some answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual having to use a concrete class name in a protocol definition. What you should do (most of the cases, exceptions may apply… though they are a bad smell) is make your class conform to a protocol, and use that class in the delegate protocol definition.

It is also a bad smell that a class needs to be its own delegate. I'd revise the design carefully.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the protocol first.  Try like below

```
@protocol LeveyPopListViewDelegate <NSObject>
//the definition for LeveyPopListViewDelegate
@end

@interface LeveyPopListView : UIView <LeveyPopListViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

//the content of LeveyPopListView

@end
```

Comment: But I want to use LeveyPopListView in protocol LeveyPopListViewDelegate

Comment: You can forward declare LeveyPopListView above the protocol definition. i.e @class LeveyPopListView;